# WCF System.TimeoutException: The socket transfer timed out after 00:00:00

Tags: wcf

I am using a wcf net tcp service hosted in WAS with windows authentication.  The service consistently fails with a particular user credentials from a particular client machine.  The credentials work on a different client machine.  Different credentials work on the client machine.  However, the service consistently fails with the error below using the particular client machine and credentials:

```
System.TimeoutException: The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The socket transfer timed out after 00:00:00. You have exceeded the timeout set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.IO.IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.TimeoutException: The socket transfer timed out after 00:00:00. You have exceeded the timeout set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.SetWriteTimeout(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Note that the timeout is after 00:00:00 even though it's configured for 00:01:00.  This leads me to believe it is not actually a timeout issue.  Here are my bindings:

```
          <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyAwesomeService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <!--<extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />-->
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
```

I am setting up E2E tracing now and will post back after I get the results.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout value you see in the exception means how much operation time is remained before timing out. So, the above may certainly turn-up the issue with timeout. the Timeout configured in your binding are low, where it seems to take more than 1 min. You can try increating timeout values, very likely the open timeout value.

HTH
Amit

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the response.  I will toggle the timeout values, but as I noted, it times out after 0 seconds.  The call should take less than a second to complete, so I don't know how it could be taking more than a minute.

Comment: Also, why do you say it's the operation time?  It looks like the open time out to me...?

Comment: Sorry, my bad...I just meant to point out the concept of how timeout is logged in exception messages. I'm not sure what you meant by " it times out after 0 seconds", do you see request failing within a second?

Comment: Thanks Amit.  RE "it times out after 0 seconds", I was just saying what is in the log.  The log shows this "The socket transfer timed out after 00:00:00.".